# Specific decimal formatting required - possible with only a format string?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

Sample code

```
    private void DoShow(decimal d)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(d.ToString("#,0.##"));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoShow(1200m);  // A - desired result : "1,200"
        DoShow(1200.60m);  // B - desired result : "1,200.60"
        DoShow(1200.58m);  // C - desired result : "1,200.58"
        DoShow(120m);  // D - desired result : "120"
    }
```

I'm trying to format decimal values to strings as shown by the "desired results" above. The formatting code used gets me close, but case B) returns "1,200.6".

The amounts are monetary values, but I don't want the dollar sign. When the cents are zero, I don't want to show the cents. Otherwise, I want to show the cents with 2 decimal places. The dollar value should have commas in them if over 999.

Is this possible with just a format string ? (It will be used in SSRS, so a format string solution would work best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific format rule for what you're asking.  If you want to conditionally format the values in a column in SSRS, you can try using an expression like this:

```
=IIF((Fields!myField.Value - CInt(Fields!myField.Value)) > 0, 
Format(Fields!myField.Value, "#,###.#0"),Format(Fields!myField.Value, "#,###"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void DoShow(decimal d)
{
    var delim = (d.ToString().Contains('.')) ? "#,###.#0" : "#,###";
    MessageBox.Show(d.ToString(delim));
}
```

This works fine for me. Not pretty though, not the best implementation.